# MIPS Direct Mapped Cache. Use of Address Bits

Tags: caching

[image]

[image]

The above have answers in blue

***Which bits will be used for what***? Eg. I know lst 2 LSB are byte offset. Then which bits will be used for word select, block select & tag?

What I did was

- 2 LSB: Byte offset
- 1 Bit: Word select
- 4 Bit: Block select
- Rest: Tag

But it appears wrong? For (a) I have

[image]

(b) incomplete I think but its already wrong

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your reasoning is incorrect:

> - 2 LSB: Byte offset
> - 1 Bit: Word select
> - 4 Bit: Block select
> - Rest: Tag

Remember that the problem says the word size is **16 bits** or two bytes, so only one address bit is used for byte offset within a word.

Again, this has absolutely nothing to do with MIPS which has a 32 or 64 bit word.